# Angular redirect to other template with data

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have two controllers as follows.

```
   .when('/list_persons', {
      templateUrl: 'views/list_persons.html',
      controller: 'topBarController',
      activetab: 'list_persons'
    })
    .when('/register_person', {
      templateUrl: 'views/register_person.html',
      controller: 'topBarController',
      activetab: 'register_person'
    })
```

In the /list_persons view I have a table with person. In the table I would like to create a icon for editing a person. When the user clicks on this icon I would like to redirect to /register_person view. I would also like add some data to the redirect(the person to edit). How can I accomplish this?

Edit: tobarController is just responsible for highlighting elements in the header based on which side you are. There are other controllers on these templates doing the main work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use routeParams for this. Just add the id of the person to edit to the path and change your routes as follows:

```
 .when('/list_persons/:personId', {
  templateUrl: 'views/list_persons.html',
  controller: 'topBarController',
  activetab: 'list_persons'
})
```

Then, within your `topBarController`, you can inject the `$routeParams`-Service which will contain the personId:

```
[...].controller('topBarController', function($scope, $routeParams){
    $scope.personId = $routeParams.personId;
}
```

If you have all your persons stored inside a Service or something, it gonna be easy to retrieve the person to edit just by the id.

Comment: Thanks. So I will have to get the person from db again when I have the personId?

Comment: No. You should in general dont get the persons within your controller. A Controller in Angular is there to wire the scope with the logic. The logic itself is better stored within a service. Services are singletons, so they will be the same Object WHEREVER you inject them. So get the list of persons wtihin a service and store them there. Then you can just inject that service in both Controller s and grab the person to edit via the ID again.

Comment: Yup as recommended here create a service that contains your logic for communicating with the server and storing and searching through the data it gets back, this can then be injected into any controllers where you need to do something with XYZ type of data (make a service for each type of data seems to work out well, one for users one for products etc.)  If you get into a problem where services need to tell each other what to do you can create a "bridge" service to communicate between the two (to avoid circular dependency)

Comment: Thanks. I already have them in a Service so I will just share it.